# Rendering code with syntax highlighting from a CMS

Tags: reactjs, strapi, prismjs

I am using a headless CMS(Strapi) and React on the frontend. I would like to render code blocks with highlighting using PrismJS (or anything).

In my render():

```
<div>
 <pre>
  <code className="language-css">{`p { color: red }`}</code>
 </pre>
 <h2>{this.state.title}</h2>
 <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `${content}` }} />
</div>
```

The code wrapped with `<pre>` tags serves as an example of what I'm trying to do.

[image: First is the pre tag example, below is what's rendered from innerHTML]

The problem is that since I'm using the Strapi CMS, the code block not recognized by PrismJS. Here's how it's rendered:

[image]

The top part is the code directly written in my component while the bottom is returned from the CMS. In the WYSIWYG of the CMS I have the following `<pre><code class="language-css">p { color: red }</code></pre>`

Is there a way that I can write content with text and code and have the code highlighted properly?

This seems like a similar issue: [React : Rendering a syntax highlighted code block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34578261/react-rendering-a-syntax-highlighted-code-block)

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem: https://github.com/akiran/react-highlight

Be sure to set your CSS in `index.html` and I added the following in my project:

```
<Highlight language="javascript" innerHTML={true}>
 {content}
</Highlight>
```

Works perfectly! Hope this helps someone.